# How to extend Transformation of Equations to two variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider this example:

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the equation $2x^2 +5x+16 = 0$ then find the equation with roots $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$.

Solution:

I learnt two methods to solve questions like these.

1. Using Vieta's Relations
   $\alpha + \beta = -5/2$ , $\alpha \times \beta = 16/2$. $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = (\alpha + \beta)^2-2\alpha \beta = \cdots$ and $\alpha^2 \times \beta^2 = (\alpha \beta)^2 = \cdots$. The required equation is $x^2 -(\alpha^2 + \beta^2)x + (\alpha^2 \beta^2) = 0 \implies \cdots = 0.  \Box$
2. Using Transformation of Equation
   Let $\alpha' = \alpha^2 \implies \alpha = \sqrt{\alpha'}$. Also $2\alpha^2 + 5\alpha +16 = 0 \implies 2(\sqrt{\alpha'})^2 + 5\sqrt{\alpha'} +16 = 0 \implies \cdots = 0$. Lastly replace $\alpha'$ with $x$.  $\Box$

But I am unable to solve the following question using the second method.

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the equation $2x^2 +5x+16 = 0$ then find the equation that has roots $\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta}$ and $\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha}$.

Here, each of the roots is a function of two variables: $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Can it be solved using Transformation of Equation?

Comment: It transforms into $5\sqrt{\alpha'}=-2\alpha'-16$, so squaring both sides should give you a quadratic.

Comment: @KentaS No, I am not asking for that. I am asking how to find an equation with roots $\alpha^2/\beta$ and $\beta^2/\alpha$ using the technique of transformation of equation.

Comment: Oh sorry; I'm bad at reading.

Answer (score 1):

Here $\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta} = \frac{(\alpha \beta)^2}{\beta^3} = \frac{(16/2)^2}{\beta^3}$. So, first transform the given equation into one that has $\frac{1}{\alpha^3} = \alpha'$ and $\frac{1}{\beta^3} = \beta'$ as its roots. Then transform this equation into one that has $(16/2)^2 \alpha' = \alpha''$ and $(16/2)^2 \beta' = \beta''$ as its roots. $\Box$

In general, if $f(\alpha,\beta)$ and $f(\beta,\alpha)$ are to be the roots of the new equation, then eliminate one of the variables by using Vieta's Relation, i.e., express the new roots either as a function of $\alpha \beta$ and $\alpha$ or as a function of  $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha$. The resulting function contains only one variable. After applying suitable transformations we will get the answer.